# Add ObjectId() as property in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I want to add references to other documents in a document but when I use [adminMongo](https://github.com/mrvautin/adminMongo) all properties containing `ObjectId()` is reset to the current documents ID when I save it. How do I set an `ObjectId()` from the shell instead? Or can I set it from adminMongo somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was an issue in earlier versions of adminMongo but the software now supports full BSON document formats.

Comment: I'm no longer working with MongoDB but I mark your post as the answer anyway, I trust you on this one :)

Answer (score 0):

From the shell you can set an `ObjectId()` by using this command:

```
db.collection.update({"_id" : ObjectId("570513aa1a0a4c4808842522")}, {$set:{"user": ObjectId("562532fd4655f16309601d93"), "organization": ObjectId("564dda1cdbb0477805afa654")}})
```

If you want an array with multiple id:s then just use `$addToSet` instead of `$set`.